# How to bridge additional IP of host over KVM?

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization, network-bridge

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04.3 on my dedicated server and I have an additional IP on my host server.

I want to create KVM on my host server and assign my additional IP to it so that it can be accessed with that IP and setup dns-server, etc.

How can I assign my additional IP as an static IP in my KVM?

What should I write in main server's /etc/network/interfaces and KVM's /etc/network/interfaces?

I looked the other questions but this one for example even turns my main server down [Bridge interfaces and KVM](https://askubuntu.com/q/39960/498411)

Comment: Does [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/638162/kvm-network-bridge-to-assign-static-ip/638269#638269) answer help you?

Comment: @DougSmythies I've tried that but when I wrote them in my interfaces my server doesn't even boot

Comment: @DougSmythies I don't know if it doesn't boot or not but I can't connect via ssh to my server

Comment: I do not know what is wrong. The answer I pointed to was tested. Could you edit your question and add the contents of your main server's and quest VM's `/etc/network/interfaces` files.

Comment: @DougSmythies It worked. I rebooted my server from my robot completely and I configured as the answer said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://askubuntu.com/a/638269/498411 - This helped!

I read that before asking this question but the problem was that I didn't completely reboot my server to setup my new interfaces.

Now it works!